# Understanding Java's Collections & Mutables - Sizes, Load factors and Thresholds

Tags: java, string, collections

I wanted to understanding the default size and the thresholds at which the Java Collections and Mutable elements grow.

I created a simple program to declare them all and the added a debugger to the last SysOut statement and then inspected the references.

I have commented the findings but, **wanted to understand the LoadFactor and Thresholds in details, if anyone can help with a simple to understand explanation.**

**Below is the program I used to get the findings -**

```
public class CollectionInfo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Integer,String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<Integer,String> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();

        Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet();
        Set<String> linkedhashSet = new LinkedHashSet();
        Set<String> treeSet = new TreeSet();

        List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList();
        List<String> linkedList = new LinkedList();
        List<String> vector = new Vector<>();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        //Table - 16, LoadFactor - 12, Threshhold - 0.75
        hashMap.put(1, "a");

        //Table - 16, LoadFactor - 12, Threshhold - 0.75
        linkedHashMap.put(1, "a");

        treeMap.put(1, "a");

        //Table - 16, LoadFactor - 12, Threshhold - 0.75
        hashSet.add("a");

        //Table - 16, LoadFactor - 12, Threshhold - 0.75
        linkedhashSet.add("a");

        treeSet.add("a");

        //ElementData - 10
        arrayList.add("a");

        //Has First and Last
        linkedList.add("a");

        vector.add("a");

        //Size - 16
        builder.append("a");

        //Size - 16
        buffer.append("a");

        System.out.println("Added debugger to this line and please inspect the references");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Simple words ,

HashMap and Hashset adjust its internals as new ones get inserted, the TreeMap does not generally adjust its nodes on adding new ones. The same way ArrayList and a LinkedList: the first adjust to resize, while the second one does not. That is why setting the initial size of a TreeMap is roughly as meaningless as trying to set the initial size of a LinkedList.

If you see hashmap and arraylist has random access  it does make sense also to define initial capacity and load factor but treemap/linkedlist has to do sequential search for accessing any value so even if you provide initial capacity its not going to make sense as the way those collections works.

The stringbuilder and stringbuffer are mutable type of string manipulation and for that you need to have random access to any characters of string so it is obvious that these two should be backed by array/arraylist kind of data structure and as I said above we need to provide initial capacity to buffer for storing string character and also javadocs says

"As long as the length of the character sequence contained in the string buffer does not exceed the capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal buffer array. If the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger."

Comment: Does that mean Collections and Mutables that have default size eg 16 or 10, they grow after each element is added to them? 
How does Load Factor and Threshold come into the picture?

Comment: For arraylist , size is depends on internal backed array , once it is full , size increase by 2 times and all elements of current arraylist will be copied to new arraylist.(So load factor concept not comes for arraylist)

Comment: For Maps , java will check after every insertion , if 

current capacity <= initial capactiy * load factor(12*0.75) = 12 

if its less or equals (like 12 in this case ) then it will increase by twice size , if provide your initial capacity then formula will still remain same only thing is your initial size will be changed , also you can provide your own load factor.

Comment: Please  check , java docs for more understanding of initial capacity and load factor 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html